# Efficient way to remove spaces between two characters in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

I am facing this problem a lot. For eg.

a b c d abcd

x y z w xyzw

Now i have to remove the spaces between only the single characters. The lines have some characters in front as well.

i want to try something like this: s/[a-z] [a-z]/**[a-z] [a-z]**/g  - what could be possible replace expression?

This is just an example of the problem. I face similar issues a lot of time when i have to apply some search to find these type of expression and replace to an expression but not replace them fully and only replace a part of it.

Edit: Want to remove single space between single characters.

Comment: Do you want to remove *single space* between characters or between *single characters*?

Comment: You want to remove spaces only between single characters, right? And not between single characters and words, or words and words?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a regular expression with collections of substrings:

```
s/\([a-z]\) \([a-z]\)/\1\2/g
```

the \1 refers to the characters matched by the regular expression between the first `\(...\)`, and \2 the characters matched by the regular expression between the second `\(...\)`

Comment: Just for knowledge, what does these use of \1 \2 called?

Comment: the stuff between `\(...\)` is a subexpression, and a \1 or \2 is often called a backreference or sometimes a reference (in my old UNIX days anyway:-) see http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/ed_4.html for example

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I had a similar problem. I wanted to remove all white spaces from all numbers in a row but keep white spaces elsewhere.

```
%s/\\([0-9]\\) \\([0-9]\\)/\1\2/g
```

did the trick.